# Multiple webcam capture in one avi with c# (windows forms)

Tags: c#, webcam, capture

I need to find a way how to make one video file from 2 or more webcam in C# (windows app). I tried to use the google for finding some samples, but no success. I found a way how to record a video from the webcam (with directshowNet, directx I can save two avi with two webcam...)

more about directShowNet:

http: //directshownet.sourceforge.net/

Sample for capturing video:

http: //www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshownet.aspx

For a simple example I have 2 webcams. I need to get the frames during the record, paste one frame near the other (make one image, create one frame from the two), and insert these new frames into a new avi. 
Any idea? Is it possible to get the frames in time, and create one new avi from the 2 captured?

Comment: is it enough to make a two image into single image

Answer (score 1):

The question is bit old(!) but just in case: I have successfully used [AForge.NET](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) library. In its 2.1.4 version it has a sample that displays video from two cameras. 
All you have to do is instead of using default Video Player control use [VideoCaptureDevice](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f4d3c2ba-605c-f066-f969-68260ce5e141.htm) and in NewFrame events create your desired bitmap. 
AForge.NET even have a [AVIWriter](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/5fedbbbe-6d28-5f69-35a2-9d7119544a2d.htm) that you can use for creating output videos.

Answer (score 0):

here this code for merge 2 images

```
#region TakeSnap Class

    IntPtr memDc;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Sizes
    {
        public Int32 cx;
        public Int32 cy;

        public Sizes(Int32 x, Int32 y)
        {
            cx = x;
            cy = y;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        public struct BLENDFUNCTION
    {
        public byte BlendOp;
        public byte BlendFlags;
        public byte SourceConstantAlpha;
        public byte AlphaFormat;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Points
    {
        public Int32 x;
        public Int32 y;

        public Points(Int32 x, Int32 y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="DeleteDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteDC(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="DeleteObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr DeleteObject(IntPtr hDc);

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="BitBlt")]
    public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hdcDest,int xDest,
        int yDest,int wDest,int hDest,IntPtr hdcSource,
        int xSrc,int ySrc,int RasterOp);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="CreateCompatibleBitmap")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hdc,
        int nWidth, int nHeight);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="CreateCompatibleDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport ("gdi32.dll",EntryPoint="SelectObject")]
    public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc,IntPtr bmp);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetDesktopWindow")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetSystemMetrics")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int abc);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="GetWindowDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(Int32 ptr);

    [DllImport("user32.dll",EntryPoint="ReleaseDC")]
    public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd,IntPtr hDc);

    protected static IntPtr m_HBitmap;
    public const int SM_CXSCREEN=0;
    public const int SM_CYSCREEN=1;
    public const int SRCCOPY = 13369376;

    #endregion



  private IntPtr get_pointer(string path)
    {

        Bitmap bitmap=new Bitmap(path);
        IntPtr oldBits = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr screenDC = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);
        IntPtr hBitmap = IntPtr.Zero;
        memDc = CreateCompatibleDC(screenDC);

        try
        {
            Point topLoc = new Point(Left, Top);
            Sizes bitMapSize = new Sizes(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            BLENDFUNCTION blendFunc = new BLENDFUNCTION();
            Points srcLoc = new Points(0, 0);

            hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color.FromArgb(0));
            IntPtr pt= SelectObject(memDc, hBitmap);
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, screenDC);               
            return memDc;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return this.Handle;
        }

    }       
    public  Bitmap GetDesktopImage()
    {
        try
        {               

            Sizes size; 
            IntPtr hBitmap;         
            IntPtr  hDC = get_pointer(@"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\11_13_40_453.jpg");             
            IntPtr hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
            IntPtr  hDC1 = get_pointer(@"C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\11_13_42_906.jpg");        

            size.cx = this.Width-2;
            size.cy = this.Height-22;
            hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx*2, size.cy);          
            if (hBitmap!=IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);                    
                BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0,size.cx,size.cy, hDC,0, 0,SRCCOPY); 
                BitBlt(hMemDC, size.cx, 0,size.cx,size.cy, hDC1,0, 0,SRCCOPY);
                SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);                         
                DeleteDC(hMemDC);                   
                DeleteDC(memDc);                    
                ReleaseDC(this.Handle, hDC);
                ReleaseDC(this.Handle, hDC1);               
                Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);                 
                DeleteObject(hBitmap);              
                GC.Collect();               
                return bmp;
            }           
            return null;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {           
            return null;
        }
    }


    private void Createimage()
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap bm= GetDesktopImage();
            bm.Save(Application.StartupPath+"\\temp\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss ff")+".Jpeg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: size.cx = this.Width-2;                        
size.cx = this.Height-22;
instant of setting your form size set your image size like(width 320,height 280)

Comment: There is a more simple way to copy 2 images near each other (with Ggraphics & DrawImageUnscaled - http://www.netcomp.nl/support/origdocs/dotnetsdk/cpref/frlrfsystemdrawinggraphicsclassdrawimageunscaledtopic3.htm).

But my main problem is not "how to merge the images", but HOW TO get and store in memory the captured images from the 2 (or more) webcam in the same time.